FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. kotlin ktor
I have a problem with my ktor project, on my local computer server works well, but when I put it on a virtual machine I have exception:
Exception in thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:161)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:132)
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FirebaseDatabase.java:81)
at `com.example.ApplicationKt.deleteOldEvents(Application.kt:532)`
`at` com.example.ApplicationKt$module$3.invokeSuspend(Application.kt:187)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)

Why is this happening?
Code:
@Serializable
data class Request(val receiverUid: String, val senderUid: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    try {
        val serviceAccount = FileInputStream("src/main/resources/google-services.json")

        val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("there is my url for database")
            .build()

        if(FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)
            println("FirebaseApp initialized successfully")
        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Error initializing FirebaseApp: ${e.message}")
    }

    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0", module = Application::module).start(wait = true)
}

fun Application.module() {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        gson {
            setPrettyPrinting()
        }
    }

    launch {
        while(true) {
            deleteOldEvents()
            delay(1000 * 3600 * 60 * 24)
        }
    }
    install(Routing) {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("Hello World!")
        }
          #other code
    }
}

suspend fun deleteOldEvents() {

    val dbEvent = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("current_events")
    val dbGroups = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("groups")
    val reports = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("reports")

    val currentTime = Instant.now().epochSecond

    suspendCoroutine<Unit> { continuation ->
        dbEvent.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                dataSnapshot.children.forEach { eventSnapshot ->
                    val timestamp = eventSnapshot.child("timestamp").value as Long
                    if (currentTime - timestamp > 5 * 24 * 60 * 60) {
                        eventSnapshot.ref.removeValue() { error, _ ->
                            
                           continuation.resume(Unit)
                           
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                continuation.resumeWithException(error.toException())
            }
        })
    }
}


How have you deployed the application on the server?

I used Ubuntu 22.04, cloud.ru and my terminal
